# Naming conventions for parameters in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, parameters, coding-style, naming-conventions

When naming parameters in Objective-C, does it matter -that is, it is advisable for documentation / legibility - if I use the same name for similar methods?  For example:

```
@interface Zookeeper : Employee

-(void) washAnimal:(Animal *)someAnimal;
-(void) feedAnimal:(Animal *)someAnimal;
-(void) trainAnimal:(Animal *)someAnimal;

...
```

Or, should it be like so:

```
@interface Zookeeper : Employee

-(void) washAnimal:(Animal *)animalToBeWashed;
-(void) feedAnimal:(Animal *)animalToBeFed;
-(void) trainAnimal:(Animal *)animalToBeTrained;

...
```

Thanks!

Comment: It is advisable to write compilable code :). Reusing the same parameter name is fine though. As long as the parameter name makes sense and isn't already used in the same method then you should use it.

Comment: Convention is convention, it depends on you and your team and for world it should be understandable. writing `animal` and `anAnimal` is good. but not `object` or `parameter`. Sometime you have a property called animal so you have to choose someother name, you may opt for `myAnimal`, `passedAnima` or even `animal_`. But not `_animal` as this may be an alias from auto-synthesized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the example you gave, I'd just use `animal` as the name for all 3. Look at `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` methods - all arguments for the table view in question are named `tableView`.